# At what point is the "Cmd Msg" of the init function delivered?

Tags: elm

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the behaviour of the `init` function. I'm trying to build a login page, which goes into the `CheckingAuth` stage upon page-load. Here's my `init` function:

```
init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init = (LoginModel Login.CheckingAuth, Cmd.map (\_ -> LoginMsg Login.CheckAuth) Cmd.none)
```

Here's a snippet of code from my `Login.Page` module:

```
type Model = CheckingAuth | Display String | Redirecting String
type Msg = CheckAuth | AuthResult (Result Http.Error (Either String (Entity User))) | RedirectTo String

update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model = 
    case (Debug.log "MSG DELIVERED" msg) of
        CheckAuth -> (CheckingAuth, Debug.log "making API request" <| Http.send AuthResult Api.login)
        -- other cases come here
```

I've tried a lot of things, but can't get the `CheckAuth` message to be delivered upon application startup.

**Edit:** I finally got something working with the following code snippet, but I have no idea why the `Cmd Msg` constructed by `Task.perform` works, but the one constructed by `Cmd.map` doesnt:

```
init = (LoginModel Login.CheckingAuth, Task.perform (always <| LoginMsg Login.CheckAuth) (Task.succeed ()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your init it not doing anything. If you map anything over a `Cmd.none` you still have a `Cmd.none`.

The command you really want to send is in your update function, so just promote that directly into init and you should be good to go:

```
init = 
    (LoginModel Login.CheckingAuth, Http.send AuthResult Api.login)
```

Your second code example does indeed have a command in it, so that returns immediately and gets passed to the update function, but as you can see, this is not simplest way to your goal.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand the `Cmd msg` model properly then. Isn't a `Cmd` essentially a non-executed IO/side-effect action (coming from a Haskell background). Irrespective of how a Cmd was constructed (either via Cmd.map or Task.perform), shouldnt it be handed over to the Elm runtime for execution?

Comment: Yes. But it less an un-exrcuted effect but data that the runtime turns into an effect